# Calculating ideals of algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> The problem is to calculate ideals of $$V(xy^3+x^3y-x^2+y) \text{ and } V(z-xy,y^2+xz-x^2).$$

the base field is algebraically closed and of course those are affine algebraic sets.
I played with them for a while but made no progress. i tried to show the ideals generated by the polynomials are prime in polynomial rings so by Hilbert's nullstellensatz the ideals of affine algebraic sets are just the ideals generated by polynomials. how can i deal with them??

Comment: Have you tried [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/)? E.g. `isPrime` tells you that they are prime.

Answer (score 1):

Since in $k[x,t,z]/(z-xy,y^2+xz-x^2)$ we have $z=xy$, this quotient is obviously isomorphic to $k[x,y]/(y^2+x^2y-x^2)$. Let us show that the polynomial $h=y^2+x^2y-x^2$ is irreducible: suppose that it is equal to $fg$.

Say a polynomial has width $k$ if $k=a-b$ with $a$ the degree of the monomial of heighest degree appearing in it and $b$ the degree of the monomial of lowest degree. For example, the width $w(h)$ of $h$ is $1$. It is easy to see that if two polynomials are both nonzero, the width of their product is the sum of their widths. It follows from this that $w(f)+w(g)=1$ and therefore we can assume that $f$ has width zero, that is, that it is homogenous, and that $g$ has width $1$.

Now call the principal part of a polynomial the sum of its terms of heights degree. The principal part of $h$ is $x^2y$. It is easy to see that the principal part of $h$ is the product of the principal parts of $f$ and of $g$. On the other hand, since $f$ is homogeneous, it is equal to its principal part: we conclude that $f$ divides $x^2y$ and is a nonzero scalar multiple of one of $x$, $x^2$, $y$, $xy$ or $x^2y$. Since none of these divide $h$, we see that we have reached a contradiction.